# Android Gradle Managed Device Test Fails Need to Read WindowHierarchy

Tags: android, android-testing, gradle-managed-device

I want to dump the window hierarchy and read from the gradle managed device the file but I keep getting File issues with writing it.  It should output it to the directory app/build/outputs/managed_device....

java.io.FileNotFoundException: window_dump.xml: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:574)

gradle command:

```
./gradlew app:phonesGroupDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.regressions.OnboardingRegressions
```

OnboardingRegressions.kt

```
...
// this finds the title but can't find and click the button
val objectTitle = device.findObject(By.textContains("to send you notifications?"))
assert(objectTitle.text.contains("to send you notifications?"))

// want to read why the Allow button is not seen, 
device.dumpWindowHierarchy(File("window_dump.xml"))

// Test fails here when above line is commented out
device.findObject(By.text("Allow")).click()
...
```

FYI the test runs perfect on emulator in the IDE but as soon as I run on managed device it can't locate the button.  FYI this is a API 34 device